# Pandas - stacking multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame built:

```
  Movies      Cost    Tickets
0   1158  0.000000   2.000000
1   1158  0.000000   0.000000
2   1158  0.000000   0.000000
3   1158  0.000000   3.000000
```

I've used stack() to change my configuration to:

```
                                           Event 1  
0              Movies                         1158
1                Cost                     0.000000
2             Tickets                     2.000000
3              Movies                         1158
4                Cost                     0.000000
5             Tickets                     0.000000
6              Movies                         1158
7                Cost                     0.000000
8             Tickets                     0.000000
9              Movies                         1158
10               Cost                     0.000000
11            Tickets                     3.000000
```

but this is stacking the data top of each other, I was looking to create a new column with the end goal being:

```
                            Event 1   Event 2   Event 3   Event 4
0              Movies          1158      1158      1158      1158
1                Cost      0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2             Tickets      2.000000  0.000000  0.000000  3.000000
```

here is my current configuration:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'Tickets': pd.Series(Tickets),
     'Movies': pd.Series(Movies),
     'Cost': pd.Series(costs)})


print(df)

df.columns.name = ''

stackEvent3 = df.stack()
stackEvent3 = df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index(name='Event1')
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Would a transposition not work? `df.T`

Comment: I really new to Pandas, care to share an example?

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: I looked up transposition and this makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
new_df = df.T.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.index, df.index+1))).add_prefix('Event ')
         Event 1  Event 2  Event 3  Event 4
Movies    1158.0   1158.0   1158.0   1158.0
Cost         0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
Tickets      2.0      0.0      0.0      3.0
```

---

to set columns name like you want [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) building a dict to replace:

```
df.T.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.index, ['brown', 'purple', 'yellow', 'blue'])))
```

or

```
new_df = df.T
new_df.columns = ['brown', 'purple', 'yellow', 'blue']
```

Comment: What if I wanted to change the Event Name to something more unique? Like brown, purple, yellow and blue. I notice this is adding a number to the columns that are being generated. Btw, thank you for the quick response!

Comment: then use `new_df.columns = ['brown', 'purple', 'yellow', 'blue']` and drop `add_prefix` simply you could use : `df.T.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.index, ['brown', 'purple', 'yellow', 'blue'])))`

Comment: You sir have saved me from breaking my head. I am new to Pandas and been searching for half the morning. But I don't know those keywords to search. Again thank you so much for all help!

Comment: I am glad to help:) please consider accept the answer!

Comment: Sorry, got one more question. Let's say I want to do math by dividing Movies by Tickets and captures its result by adding a new row or column on depending on what's best. Would you recommend doing math before the transpose or after?